# Websocket get parameters from query

Tags: javascript, websocket, steam

I'm using node.js with websocket module (https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node)
I need to get player's steam ID from the passed parameter.
I connect to websocket using following query:

```
ws://localhost:8080/steamid=76561198024683679
```

On the server side, how do I get **steamid** using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can send this id after connection established. You can emit an event like `join` with this id and on server side get this id via this event.

```
socket.emit('join', steamId);
```

Comment: I don't need to send back the steamID to client, I need to use the steamID further in the server itself